# Fatal error: Call to a member function add_section() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am trying to add a section to a panel to add a section for lazy load image option.  I keep getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_section() on null on line 91.

I have the panel setup in a different file.

```
$wp_customize->add_panel(
'aviation_theme_options',
array(
    'priority' => 7,
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'theme_supports' => '',
    'title' => esc_html__('Theme Option', 'aviation'),
)
```

);

*The file that I am getting the error on is in the section.*

```
/**
 * Theme options.
 */
$wp_customize->add_section(
    'lazy_load_options', array(
        'title'    => __( 'Lazy-load images', 'aviation' ),
                    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'panel' => 'aviation_theme_options',
        'priority' => 6,

    )
);

if ( function_exists( 'aviation_lazyload_images' ) ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'lazy_load_media', array(
            'default'           => 'lazyload',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'aviation_sanitize_lazy_load_media',
            'transport'         => 'postMessage',

        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'lazy_load_media', array(
            'label'           => __( 'Lazy-load images', 'aviation' ),
            'section'         => 'lazy_load_options',
                            'settings'        => 'lazy_load_media',
            'type'            => 'radio',
            'description'     => __( 'Lazy-loading images means images are loaded only when they are in view. Improves performance, but can result in content jumping around on slower connections.', 'aviation' ),
            'choices'         => array(
                'lazyload'    => __( 'Lazy-load on (default)', 'aviation' ),
                'no-lazyload' => __( 'Lazy-load off', 'aviation' ),
            ),
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'aviation_customize_register' );
```

Comment: So `$wp_customize` has not been initialised to anything or when you did, it failed

Comment: And what **exactly** does `$wp_customize` contain? Have you checked whether that variable might be `null`?

Comment: As this is wordpress, maybe you need to throw another `global` into the mix

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to this.  I have the $wp_customize  as this function aviation_customize_register( $wp_customize )